# From Table A to Table B transfer random column values

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I have two tables, I wish that Table B would have random Table A values assigned to a specific column.

Table A:

```
SubscriptionID  | Number | SubStart | SubEnd  | MobPhoneID
1                  321    2013-01     NULL        NULL
2                  123    2013-02    2014-02      NULL
3                  321    2013-03     NULL        NULL
4                  444    2013-04    2013-04      NULL
5                  555    2013-05     NULL        NULL
```

Table B:

```
MobPhoneID | Manufacturer
    1          Samsung
    2            LG
    3           Apple
    4            Sony
```

My goal is:

```
SubscriptionID  | Number | SubStart | SubEnd  | MobPhoneID
    1              321    2013-01     NULL        3
    2              123    2013-02    2014-02      NULL
    3              321    2013-03     NULL        2
    4              444    2013-04    2013-04      NULL
    5              555    2013-05     NULL        4
```

Current code that I have:

```
UPDATE TableA
SET MobPhoneID= t2.MobPhoneID
FROM TableA t1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 MobPhoneID
    FROM TableB
    WHERE t1.SubEnd IS NULL
    ORDER BY newid()
    ) t2
```

The goal is to give the random phone to a person which subscription does not end.

The SQL query above results in the following output:

```
SubscriptionID  | Number | SubStart | SubEnd  | MobPhoneID
        1           321    2013-01     NULL        2
        2           123    2013-02    2014-02      NULL
        3           321    2013-03     NULL        2
        4           444    2013-04    2013-04      NULL
        5           555    2013-05     NULL        2
```

It does not add random values, it selects only one random value and applies to all of them.

My wish is so that each person would get a random phone.

I hope my issue makes sense, I cannot seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The t1.SubEnd is Null causes it to pick the same top 1 everytime - if you set it to equal itself, then it reevaluates it.

```
  UPDATE TableA
    SET MobPhoneID= t2.MobPhoneID
    FROM TableA t1
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 MobPhoneID
        FROM TableB
        WHERE t1.SubEnd = t1.SubEnd
        ORDER BY newid()
        ) t2
```

I've previously used this method and got the expected results.

Comment: Thanks, this works, it adds MobilePhoneID to all of the tables in TableA, how can I do that instead of applying randomly to all, they would apply only to IF SubEnd is Null? The reason my WHERE t1.SubEnd IS NULL was that so I could do it.

Comment: Try: WHERE t1.SubscriptionID  = t1.SubscriptionID   AND t1.SubEnd IS NULL - I'll update the answer if it works!

Comment: I have tried, it affects 0 rows. In this case, it does not work.

Comment: Move the 'subend is null to after the join - but keep the subscription = subscription' ?

Comment: Just tried it, same situation states that 0 rows have been affected.

Answer (score 0):

If a mobile phone can be assigned only once?
Then assigning by random row_number could do it.

> ```
> ;with A as (
>   select *, row_number() over (order by SubStart) rn
>   from TableA
>   where subend is null
> )
> , B as (
>   select *, row_number() over (order by newid()) rn
>   from TableB
> ) 
> update A
> set MobPhoneID = B.MobPhoneID
> from B 
> where B.rn = A.rn
> ```

> ```
> select a.*, b.Manufacturer
> from TableA a
> left join TableB b on b.MobPhoneID = a.MobPhoneID
> order by SubscriptionID
> ```
>
> ```
> SubscriptionID | Number | SubStart | SubEnd  | MobPhoneID | Manufacturer
> -------------: | -----: | :------- | :------ | ---------: | :-----------
>              1 |    321 | 2013-01  | null    |          3 | Apple       
>              2 |    123 | 2013-02  | 2014-02 |       null | null        
>              3 |    321 | 2013-03  | null    |          1 | Samsung     
>              4 |    444 | 2013-04  | 2013-04 |       null | null        
>              5 |    555 | 2013-05  | null    |          2 | LG
> ```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=69d6231172c2e9fa311b3aeb9f2a0949)*